# Subspace of $ P_3(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $p_0,p_1\in P_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $p_0(x)=5, p_1(x)=1+x$. Suppose that $U=\operatorname{span}(p_0,p_1)$. Find a subspace $W$ of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$ P_3(\mathbb{R}) = U \oplus W,$$ here $\oplus$ denotes direct sum of subspaces and $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ denotes Polynomials with degree at most $3.$

What I have done:

By $U=\operatorname{span}(p_0,p_1)$, we get $U=\{5c_1  + c_2 (1+x) | c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}.$ Then I think we need such $W$ subspace of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$
$ P_3(\mathbb{R}) = U \oplus W.$
Now to show the above statement I think we need to show two things

1. $ P_3(\mathbb{R}) = U \oplus W$
2. $U$ and $W$ are linearly independent.

But what appropriate $W$ can I use here. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @Surb Polynomials with degree smaller and equal to 3

Comment: Why don't you take just $W=\text{Span}\{x^2,x^3\}$ ?

Comment: @Surb Thank You.

Comment: It is worth to mentioned that $U=\operatorname{span}(1, x).$ Then you can see that there is only one choice for $W.$

Comment: @Bumblebee: There are infinitely many choices for $W$...

Comment: @Surb: Yes, I see that I have  made a wrong claim. I can see $4$ different choices for $W,$ but not infinitely many. Could you add little bit more to your comment.

Comment: @Bumblebee: To make things easier, look at $\mathbb R^2$ and $U=\text{Span}\{(1,0)\}$. All $W_{(a,b)}:=\text{Span}\{(a,b)\}$ where $b\neq 0$ and $a\in \mathbb R$ will be a supplementary space. So, there are even an uncountable number of supplementaries spaces... many of them will be the same, but for example, for all $\theta \in (0,\pi)$, the spaces $W_\theta =\text{Span}\big\{\big(\cos(\theta) ,\sin(\theta )\big)\big\}$ will be different supplementaries spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $P_3(\Bbb R)$ is the vector space of dimension 4 (not 3), then say $W = \{c_3x^2+c_4x^3\mid c_3,c_4\in\Bbb R\}$ is the subspace you're searching.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can take a look at completing the basis of your original vector space. As you know, the direct sum of $U$ and $W$ gives you the vector space $P_3(\mathbb{R})$, and looking at dimensions you can say that $dim_{\mathbb{R}}P_3(\mathbb{R}) = dim_{\mathbb{R}}U +dim_{\mathbb{R}}W$. If you think about it the basis that you are looking for, is actualy the set that contains an $dim_{\mathbb{R}}P_3(\mathbb{R}) - dim_{\mathbb{R}}U$ number of vectors that are linearly independent from the ones in the $U$ basis. In a practical way, you can do the following:

1º- You put the coordinates of the basis of $U$ in the lines of a matrix. Let's call it A:
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
2º - In this step you should do a kinda like a Gaussian elimination (don't know a better name for that in english, sorry), then you'll get a matrix, lets say $A'$  like this:
$$ A' = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
3º - Now what you need to do is just complete a $dim_{\mathbb{R}}P_3(\mathbb{R})\times dim_{\mathbb{R}}P_3(\mathbb{R})$ matrix, in this case $4\times 4$, in such a way that you place a non-zero number in the $k$-$th$ column of the following rows, were $k$ should be the first column were a number is "missing". Let's call it $M$:
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If you take the rows that you have added you will get the set $B = \{x^2, x^3\}$ (by the vectors of the third and fourth rows $v_3 = (0\ 0\ 1\ 0)$ and $v_4 = (0\ 0\ 0\ 1)$ ), that is in fact a basis for the $W$ vector sub-space. So your answer could be:
$$ W = \{c_3 x^2 + c_4 x^3\ |\ c_3, c_4 \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Sorry for the big answer and I hope it helps you. The process may seem silly because we had your basis vectors for $U$ realy simple, but when it isn't that clear it realy helps.